Why is TPL Post response different in Bounded BroadcastBlock and BufferBlock?
I expected that result1 in the last assertion equal false on BroadcastBlock as on BufferedBlock, but it is not the case.
I'm using latest System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow version 8.0.1
            var block2 = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 2 });
            var result2 = block2.Post(1);
            result2 = block2.Post(1);
            
            Debug.Assert(result2 == true);
            
            result2 = block2.Post(1);
            Debug.Assert(result2 == false);   // this is expected and work

            var block1 = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i => i, new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 2});
            var result1 = block1.Post(1);
            
            result1 = block1.Post(1);
            Debug.Assert(result1 == true);

            result1 = block1.Post(1);
            Debug.Assert(result1 == false);   // this fails

Is that a bug or expected?

"Provides a buffer for storing at most one element at time, overwriting each message with the next as it arrives.". Looks like it's working as intended?

Post response is "true if the item was accepted by the target block; otherwise, false." according  link . As I'm using bounded buffer my understanding is that it should no more accept the 3rd item.

Yep. Given that the documentation for BroadcastBlock says that it will overwrite each message with the next as it arrives (so by implication is must ignore BoundedCapacity), what makes you think that the second Post should fail?

yes... Is Post() not supposed to work the same way for BufferBlock and BroadcastBlock ?

Reading the source, it looks like, when you post an item to a BroadcastBlock, it immediately tries to give it to everything which has been linked to it, then discards the item. I would therefore assume that if one of the things linked to the BroadcastBlock refused a new item, calls to BroadcastBlock.Post might start returning false, once its capacity has been reached?

That said, interestingly, I can't replicate what you're seeing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/613DuV. Given that BroadcastBlock seems to forward the message to its consumers asynchronously, this might just be racey. And actually, adding a sleep means I do match what you're seeing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVpOVj. So yes I stand by my conclusion.

Reading the source, it looks like the BroadcastBlock adds the new message to an internal queue, then asynchronously tries to forward it to all consumers. Once that's done, it removes it from its internal queue.
If you've set a capacity on the internal queue (with BoundedCapacity), and that queue has filled up (so you've added items faster than it's been able to offer them to all consumers), then Post will return false.
In your test, because the task of forwarding the item happens asynchronously on a background thread, there's a race between how quickly you can add items, vs how quickly it can offer them to all consumers. On DotNetFiddle, your final Post returns false, however if I add a sleep before the final Post (to give the background thread a chance to clear the internal queue), the final Post returns true.

your second fidder with delay is closer to my real code (as I extracted my example from an app with more code). With this delay it fails to return the right status. my conclusion is that it is a bug

Why do you think it's a bug? I think I've managed to explain the behaviour here, and it appears to be behaving according to its design

because behavior is different than with BufferBlock. "Provides a buffer for storing at most one element at time, overwriting each message with the next as it arrives." is ok. But my point here is the Post response BufferBlock vs BroadcastBlock.

But it's not the same thing as a BufferBlock. Why is it a bug if it behaves differently? It is different

ok understood you point
